# "Hook already exists: pre-push" after adding new git hook

Tags: git, git-lfs, husky

In a git repository, where we already have a .Net solution, we recently added an angular part.

For this angular part, we did add some hooks with husky. Since the frontend, that contains the package.json is in a subfolder, we did the following:

1. npm install husky --save-dev
2. Ran `cd .. && husky install ./Frontend/.husky`
3. Added a "prepare" script: `"prepare": "cd .. && husky install ./Frontend/.husky"`
4. ran `npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "cd ./Frontend && npm run lint"`
5. We also added a hook to do the automatic npm install after getting the code: `npx husky add .husky/post-merge "cd ./Frontend && npx git-pull-run --pattern 'package-lock.json' --command 'npm install'"`

This seems to work fine locally, but when the repository is checked out by our CI agent(azure devop), we get an error:

```
Syncing repository: XXX (Git)
Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'git.exe'.
git version
git version 2.30.2.windows.1
git lfs version
git-lfs/2.13.3 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.16.2; git a5e65851)
git config --get remote.origin.url
git clean -ffdx
git reset --hard HEAD
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.https://xxx@dev.azure.com/yyy/zzz/_git/aaa.extraheader
git config --get-all http.extraheader
git config --get-regexp .*extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy
git config http.version HTTP/1.1
git lfs install --local
Hook already exists: post-merge

    #!/usr/bin/env sh
    . "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"
    
    cd ./Frontend && npx git-pull-run --pattern 'package-lock.json' --command 'npm install'

To resolve this, either:
  1: run `git lfs update --manual` for instructions on how to merge hooks.
  2: run `git lfs update --force` to overwrite your hook.
##[error]Git-lfs installation failed with exit code: 2
```

This error doesn't happen when azure devop has a clean repository, but on the second run only.

I tried to run the git lfs update --manual/--force commands, without any changes.

How to properly integrate git-lfs with git hooks?

Answer (score 1):

Husky and LFS use some of the same hooks and the error message you're seeing here is due to LFS failing to install a hook that Husky has already 'reserved' so to speak.

There is a great solution documented here:
https://dev.to/mbelsky/pair-husky-with-git-lfs-in-your-javascript-project-2kh0

In a nutshell, you need to install the LFS hooks first, move them to a separate directory and then install the Husky hooks.

```
$ rm -rf .git/hooks
$ git lfs install
$ mv .git/hooks ./lfs-hooks
$ rm -rf node_modules/husky
$ npm install
```

Then you need to update your Husky configuration to ensure that LFS still runs when you need it (as it no longer has it's hooks in the .git/hooks folder).

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "post-checkout": "echo $HUSKY_GIT_STDIN | lfs-hooks/post-checkout $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "post-commit": "echo $HUSKY_GIT_STDIN | lfs-hooks/post-commit $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "post-merge": "echo $HUSKY_GIT_STDIN | lfs-hooks/post-merge $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "pre-push": "echo $HUSKY_GIT_STDIN | lfs-hooks/pre-push $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  },
```

Alternatively, [git-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-hooks) apparently offers a better integration with LFS for those happy to try another tool.

Note that this issue only affects some earlier versions of Husky so it sounds like you may be using a newer version locally but an older version in your pipeline.

Comment: The issue I've is that this git-lfs install is done by our azure devop agents, to ensure that if its a new agent, it gets LFS. Also another specific thing is that Husky is actually installed in a subfolder. Git-hooks is an alternative of husky? Or a tools used by husky?